# Issue with hoverColumn and tootip display on gRaphael?

Tags: graphael, linegraph

I can get the line graph to be displayed using gRaphael, but I have a problem with tooltips. Tooltip is displayed only for certain columns, not all the columns. I don't know if it's a problem with too much data, but 207 columns shouldn't be too bad. The canvas size is 900x300. The following is the sample code.... Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

```
var r = Raphael('lgraph');

//Some code here to prep dates, x, prep ccp, ctr, searchp arrays

var linec = r.linechart(10,10,900,300,x,[ccp,ctr,searchp],
                        { nostroke: false, 
                          axis: "0 0 1 1", 
                          symbol: "circle",
                          axisxlabels: dates, 
                          axisxtype: " ",
                          smooth: true })
linec.hoverColumn(function () {
  this.popups = r.set();
  for (var i = 0, ii = this.y.length; i < ii; i++) {
    this.popups.push(r.popup(this.x, this.y[i], this.values[i]).insertBefore(this));
  }
}, function () {
  this.popups && this.popups.remove();
});
linec.symbols.attr({ r: 3 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `ak.sort()` in **g.line-min.js** with `ak.sort(function(a,b) {return a-b});`
or `Xs.sort();` in **g.line.js** (line 185) with `Xs.sort(function(a,b) {return a-b});`

Found the solution here https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/g.raphael/issues/19#issuecomment-3766164